# refering to instance of a class from its metaclass python

Tags: python-3.x, metaclass, method-call

Is there any way to refer to instance of a class from its metaclass every time an instance is created? I suppose I should use dunder _*call*_ method inside metaclass for that purpose.

I have the following code:

```
class meta(type):   
    def __call__(cls):
       super().__call__()
       #<--- want to get an object of A class here every time when instance of A class is created

class A(metaclass = meta):
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.c = 2

    def test(self):
        print('test called')
   
a1=A()
a2=A()
a3=A()
```

Also why when I implement `__call__` method inside metaclass all created instances of my class became NoneType however when overring `__call__` I used `super().__call__()`?
For example `a4.test()` returns AttributeError: **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'test'**

Comment: Of course, *because your `__call__` method **returns `None`***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newly created instance is returned by `super().__call__()` - you hav to keep this value in a variable, use t for whatever you want and return it.

Otherwise, if the metaclass `__call__` has no return statement, all instances are imediatelly de-referenced and destroyed, and the code trying to create instances just get `None`:

```py
class meta(type):   
    def __call__(cls):
       obj = super().__call__()
       # use obj as you see fit
       ...
       return obj
```